# Creating Directories and Extracting HTML Tags With Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, mkdir

Objective - I have a file that contains html image tags that I wanted to extract and save them in separate folders. There are a lot of images and I wanted to use node.js to automate all that for me.

Question - what is the alternative approach to extracting the html image tags using node knowing that I can have html files on the server side but can’t use a document method like document.getElementsByTag for example?

Thank you.

Comment: Try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-parser for nodejs

Comment: Is your file is a static html or a template file ?! you can read the content and do a regex to extract the image tags. Then use http client to hit the url and download the image to target folder. Or if its relative / absolute path, then copy the img to required tgt folder